# Inline CSS Email CTA Buttons not appearing in Outlook Office 365 W\why?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I keep running into a problem with this Inline HTML/CSS process when I'm coding this direct mail email campaign. For some reasons the CTA buttons won't appear or render in Outlook Office 365. Have a geez at the code below and tell me if you notice any problems that I may have missed that could be causing this.

#### Inline code

```
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="callToActionButton" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-radius: 10px;box-shadow: 5pt;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #D83826; 4px;box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #D83826;">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" class="callToActionButtonContent" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;padding-top: 20px;padding-right: 40px;padding-bottom: 40px;padding-left: 40px;color: #F2F2F2;display: block;font-size: 24px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: -1px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;">
<a href="mailto:mark.nicholls@informpros.com?subject=Aussie Day Enquiry" target="_blank" title="square gallery" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #F2F2F2;display: block;font-size: 24px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: -1px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;">Email our expert</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

**This is how it should render in 0365**

[image]

**This is how it actually renders in O365** 
[image]

no red box?

Comment: ` .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display emails at full width. */
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div{line-height:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display line heights normally. */
table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up. */
#outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook 2007 and up to provide a "view in browser" message. */

Comment: `img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;} /* Force IE to smoothly render resized images. */
body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent Windows- and Webkit-based mobile platforms from changing declared text sizes. */`

Comment: the above are my client specific styles.

Comment: When is someone, or some entity going to codify html / css styling guidelines for email? This is utterly ridiculous. Outlook ditching CSS styles after they had made it possible for earlier versions? All the jumping through hoops. It should not be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't support "display" and "padding", a better way is to use a border.

This is a nice link to see what is supported by Outlook. 
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Example:

```html
<a style="text-align:center; background-color: red; border-top: solid 8px red; border-right: solid 14px red; border-left: solid 14px red; border-bottom: solid 8px red;">Clickity Click</a>
```